# Diff. between a web server and a media server?

Tags: html, webserver, red5, flash-media-server

Can some please explain me in-detail. Can't i just upload flv or other media files to my web server and play them on a webpage with embed tags? Why do i need media server for this? Or when do i need a media server?

Answer (score 0):

You do need a media server for things like automatic bandwidth selection and Flash video streams from the client (like in a video chat application). Some people also use a media server to obscure the content delivery, mostly for contractual (read: non-technical) reasons.

If you don't need any of the above features, a webserver is completely fine for video delivery - youtube uses webservers for most of its videos, after all.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Can anyone provide more info. on this?

Comment: @sam What more do you want to know? ;) I'm afraid that you'll have to give more detailed questions if you want detailed answers. Also, if this answer does not answer a part of your questions, feel free to point out that part here in the comments.